# Python 2.7, enum34 and user friendly unicode representation of enum properties

Tags: python-2.7, enums, python-unicode

I'm using enum34 in Python 2.7 to write different options to a database (Using Flask and Flask-Admin), the enum looks like this:

```
class Veggie(enum.Enum):
    celery = 1
    tomato = 2
    broccoli = 3
```

I then use it as follows to assign values as choices:

```
my_veggie = Veggie.celery
```

I'm using integers because this is how I want it to be stored in the database, as integers.

When I output this, however, to the end user, unicode(Veggie.celery), will give the following string: Veggie.celery, but instead I'd like to have it as a user friendly string, such as "Veggie: Celery", "Veggie: Tomato", etc.... I could obviously manipulate the string returned by unicode(), but I'm suspecting there should be an easier, cleaner way to do this using a class method or something built in with enum?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the string output of your `Enum` class, simply add your own `__str__` method:

```
class Veggie(Enum):
    celery = 1
    tomato = 2
    broccoli = 3
    def __str__(self):
       return self.__class__.__name__ + ': ' + self.name

>>> Veggie.tomato
<Veggie.tomato: 2>
>>> print Veggie.tomato
Veggie: tomato
```

If you do this a lot, create your own base class:

```
class PrettyEnum(Enum):
    def __str__(self):
       return self.__class__.__name__ + ': ' + self.name
```

and inherit from it:

```
class Veggie(PrettyEnum):
    celery = 1
    tomato = 2
    broccoli = 3
```